# Output of neurons in Multiple Layer Perceprton Classifier in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am currently working on [MLPClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn-neural-network-mlpclassifier) of neural_network package of sklearn.

I trained the classifier and it is predicting/running fine. Now I need the output values of neurons(nodes) in each layers when it predicts class for a particular input **after training**, for visualisation purposes.

I read the api and there is an attribute -  `coefs_` which returns the weight matrix of the network but couldn't find any method or attribute which would return the output of neurons.

So being not mentioned in the documentation, I suppose it is not possible to get it directly. Is there any way/tweaking available to get these output of neurons at each layer OR alternatively any direct method of visualisation of the MLPClassifier.

Note - MLPClassifier is currently not available in stable version of scikit-learn and is 0.18 dev version only.

I am using Python 2.7 and scikit-learn 0.18 dev version.

Comment: I think [`MLPClassifier.decision_function(X)`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.decision_function) does what you want. Edit: Correction - it is not what you want. I hadn't realized you want te outputs of individual layers.

Answer (score 1):

Output of neurons only makes sense if you have inputs. It's not an intrinsic part of the model. You take an inner product of the inputs with the weights to get the "outputs".

Comment: Exactly, that is i was wondering that is there any method which takes in a input and returns the output of neurons on each layer. btw thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think there is a method for that but should be straightforward to compute directly.